# Eclipse Java SWT Images not loading

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, swt

I am building a Java app using Eclipse and SWT. My app shows all images when I run it from Eclipse, but when i create a runnable .jar file, no images appear (I use images in my Buttons and Labels).

[image: Here is my project structure]

Here is how I am trying to use my image:

```
String redCircleString = "resources/redCircle.png";
        Image redCircleImage = new Image(display, redCircleString);
        charge_done_display_label.setImage(redCircleImage);
```

I have tried using an InputString using
`getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(file name)`

but i get a NullPointerException when i use the input stream in my new Image();
How can i solve this?

Comment: `getResourceAsStream()` operates off the classpath. Was "resources/redCircle.png" relative to an entry on your classpath when you tried it?

Comment: `Image image = new Image (display, MainScreen.class.getResourceAsStream ("redCircle.png"));` (without `resources/` since the two source folders are compiled into - probably - the same output folder and `MainScreen` is in the default package). See e.g. https://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet164.java#n35

Comment: @howlger worked! thank you